# Check a MySQL database periodically

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL` Database, and I want to check the data in this database for every day automatically.

what I mean is to test periodically for data in database, if my test is true, the script will be executed automatically.

Is there any way to do that in `MySQL` ?

Comment: what kind of script? what is your mysql server's operating system?

Comment: There is, using MySQL's Event scheduler and having a UDF called sys_exec which allows you to execute an external program. This should be sufficient to get you googling about the two.

Comment: You could also use a cron to run a shell script and have that shell script (1) call whatever function you need to test and then (2) execute whatever other scripts should be executed in response.

Comment: @Sebas I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: You should create a cron job and maybe PHP could help you also with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, create a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to call a php script every day.

If the script is located on your machine, you can call it using `php-cli`, if online, you can also use `wget`.